# How to access the wrapped value of a @Published property when passing to generic function

Tags: swift, combine

When I pass a property which is declared as `@Published` to a generic function, I get an error referring to the published value. It's fine anywhere else where I use the variable, just not when passing into the generic function.

Error:

```
error: cannot convert value 'user' of type 'User?' to expected type 'Published<User?>.Publisher?', use wrapper instead
```

Here's the playground code:

```swift
struct User {}

class Test {
    @Published var user: User?
}

func normalFunc(_ argument: User?) -> User? {
    return argument
}

func genericFunc<T>(_ argument: T?) -> T? {
    return argument
}

let test = Test()
normalFunc(test.user) // Ok
genericFunc(test.user) // Error
```

The best I have been able to do is wrap the value in parenthesis, like so:

```
genericFunc((test.user)) // Ok!
```

Comment: Confirmed bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11654

Comment: @matt I removed the edit from the post and made it an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Very cool, thanks. And thanks for reporting this bug and sticking with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a confirmed error and has been fixed with https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/30129